# how to invoke gcloud commands using terraform

Tags: redis, terraform, gcloud

Since terraform does not have redis tls support yet, was planning to invoke gcloud command to create tls enabled redis through terraform. I am new to terraform, so was looking for some resource on web. but couldn't find much. Can some one please help with a working sample. any gcloud command invocation would work.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform builds upon underlying REST APIs and does not use Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) directly. For this reason, it's not straightforward to invoke `gcloud` commands directly in the absence of a provider supporting the resource.

I'm unfamiliar with Terraform but I expect (!?) that invoking shell commands directly (e.g. `gcloud redis instances create ...`) is discouraged. And, while it's likely also possible to call REST APIs directly, you'll then need to take care authenticating.

That said, [`google-beta`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google-beta/latest) supports TLS.

[`transit_encryption_mode = "SERVER_AUTHENTICATION"`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/redis_instance#transit_encryption_mode)

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google-beta = {
      source = "hashicorp/google-beta"
      version = "3.58.0"
    }
  }
}

variable "project" {}
variable "region" {}
variable "zone" {}
variable "key" {}
variable "instance" {}

provider "google-beta" {
  credentials = file(var.key)
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}

resource "google_redis_instance" "cache" {
  provider = google-beta
  name = var.instance
  tier = "BASIC"
  memory_size_gb = 1
  location_id = var.zone
  transit_encryption_mode = "SERVER_AUTHENTICATION"
}
```

Then to confirm TLS-enabled:

```sh
gcloud redis instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(transitEncryptionMode)"
SERVER_AUTHENTICATION
```